# Express middleware confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app like this:

```
import express from 'express';

const middleware = tag => (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('middleware ' + tag);
  next();
};

const app = express();

const router = express.Router();

router.use(middleware('a'));

router.get('/x', (req, res) => res.json({ message: 'x' }));

app.use(router);

app.use(middleware('b'));

app.get('/y', (req, res) => res.json({ message: 'y' }));

app.use(middleware('c'));

app.listen(3000);
```

However, `Router` does not behave as I expected:

```
$ curl localhost:3000/x
```

> middleware a

```
$ curl localhost:3000/y
```

> middleware a
>
> middleware b

Why does hitting `/y` call the middleware? I thought that the middleware was only applied to `router`.

How can I apply a middleware to only `router`, and not the other routes in `app`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you've done it via a router, because you then attached the router with no sub-path it bundled everything together. In your example you have attached everything to the same parent endpoint `/`, so even though it's done via a router you are then attaching this router to the `/` path.

If you want to just separate middleware out as you've indicated then you have two options.

1. Sub-path the endpoints to something like `/feature1/x` and `/feature2/y`. Attach the middleware to the `/feature1` and `/feature2` respectively. This will give you the desired outcome. This could be done by attaching your router for endpoint `/x` in this way:

   ```
   app.use('/feature1', router);
   ```

Which would mean you now have the endpoints `/feature1/x` and `/y`. Each triggering it's independent chain of middleware.

2. Attach the middleware to the specific endpoint such as:

   ```
   app.get('/x, middleware('a'), (req, res) => res.json({message: 'x'});
   app.get('/y', middleware('b'), (req, res) => res.json({message: 'y'});
   ```

What you've done at the moment is attach everything to the same route path (in this case the top level slash `/`).

Comment: Are these the only two options? I have many routes on `router` and I would like to avoid boiler-plate. The routes on `router` do not share a common sub-path.

Comment: Sadly yes as middleware is mounted on a per-route basis, at least I've never seen another approach and can't think of a way of doing it!

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
app.use(router);
```

you mount the router at the root `/` path of your app. The router's middleware

```
router.use(middleware('a'));
```

is mounted at the root path or the router, and so at the root path of the app. Middleware mounted at the root path is executed for every request.

> How can I apply a middleware to only router, and not the other routes in app?

You can mount the router at `/x` and make the router handle `/` its root path:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({ message: 'x' }));
app.use('/x', router);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the routes on `router` do not share a common sub-path. This was just an example.

Comment: @sdgfsdh middlewares are mounted on per-path basis, so I don't see other options rather than attaching the middleware to every path, or having a single "catch all" middleware that alters its logic based on `req.url` for example.